# Updating Windows Form - Visual C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Hi I am currently writing a windows form application using visual studio 2010, the application I am writing needs to update labels on the form independent of any events happening - I know it is possible to update the form using event handlers but this requires and event to happen to do something.

I am planning to to use some form of main loop to update the form constantly - I just do not know where to place such a loop? I think I've heard of something called the message loop, would it go there? Or would I have to create a separate thread to do so - and if I did create a separate thread , would I have problems accessing controls created in another thread?

Basically I am modelling an elevator system and need to update certain details about the elevator to the form constantly without any buttons being pressed , e.g current floor, going up down ect

I can post code if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly want to do the background work in a worker thread. Have that worker thread send updated data to the main thread in a way that triggers an event. The main thread then updates the UI based on the updated data in reaction to the event you triggered.